# SPDT mechanical relay: do NO and NC pins short between each other as pole switches

Tags: relay, switching, short-circuit

I have a mechanical SPDT relay ([Digi-Key PN 281-6348-ND](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1542460000/281-6348-ND/9843332/), I am only using one of the two channels).  I also have a sensitive circuit downstream of the relay.

> [image: https://static-cdn.imageservice.cloud/2754108/different-types-of-relays-their-construction-operation-applications.png]

([Image source](https://static-cdn.imageservice.cloud/2754108/different-types-of-relays-their-construction-operation-applications.png))

While a mechanical relay is switching, is there a chance that the NC and NO pins can make contact of any kind?  Or is this something one should never have to worry about?

---

Bonus: is there a "relay speak" term associated with potential shorting?

Comment: Google "break before make" and "make before break". As far as I know, getting make before break behavior from an electromechanical relay would require specifically ordering a part with make before break as a special feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your part indicates from the characteristics table on Digikey that it is a DPDT Form C switch, meaning that it is a "break before make" kind of switch, and that behavior should be guaranteed as that is intentional. So, the switch is disengaged from one terminal before contacting the next: there should not ever be a connection. Form D is the "make before break" kind, where a connection between both terminals does occur. Here is a link talking a little more about relays and the different forms: [Instructables.com](https://www.instructables.com/id/All-You-Need-to-Know-About-Relays/)

Comment: Thank you @jakob!  To add, I did some additional research.  This NI article (https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/documentation/supplemental/06/understanding-switch-topologies.html) provides some nice schematics describing this further